# How to edit record in java text file?

Tags: java, file-io, text-files

I have a simple problem

I have a java text file which has records like this:

```
Hamada 115599
Johny  1478523
Bosy   753621
```

This text file defines the username and password of many accounts in a java program.

I wrote a simple code to edit password of user's account.

```
System.out.println("Change Account Password");
System.out.printf("Username: ");
String user4 = input.next();
System.out.printf("Password: ");
int pass4 = input.nextInt();
boolean checkaccount = false;
Scanner x = null;
try {
    x = new Scanner(new File("C:\\Users\\فاطمة\\Downloads\\accounts.txt"));
    while (x.hasNext()) {
        String a = x.next();
        int b = x.nextInt();
        if ((a == null ? user4 == null : a.equals(user4)) && pass4 == b) checkaccount = true;
    }
    if (checkaccount) {
        int newpass = 0;
        boolean checked = true;

        File f = new File("C:\\Users\\فاطمة\\Downloads\\accounts.txt");
        File tempFile2 = new File("C:\\Users\\فاطمة\\Downloads\\accounts2.txt");
        BufferedWriter writer2 = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(tempFile2));

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(f);

        Scanner sc2 = new Scanner(System. in );

        int foo = Integer.parseInt(user4);

        while (sc.hasNext()) {
            String currentLine1 = sc.nextLine();
            String[] tokens = currentLine1.split(" ");
            if (Integer.valueOf(tokens[0]) == foo && checked) {
                sc2.nextLine();
                System.out.printf("New Password: ");
                newpass = sc2.nextInt();
                currentLine1 = tokens[0] + " " + newpass;
                checked = false;
            }
            writer2.write(currentLine1 + System.getProperty("line.separator"));
        }
        writer2.close();
        sc.close();
        f.delete();
        boolean successfull1 = tempFile2.renameTo(f);
        if (successfull1 == true) System.out.println("Password changed successfully.");
        else System.out.println("Error occurred during changing password.");
    } else System.out.println("Wrong username or password... try again !!");
} catch (Exception e) {}
```

first of all, the program checks if account exists, if it was, then the program allows the user to change password but when i run this code nothing happens and not show me the output statements of "New password: "

what is the wrong with this code ?

Comment: You mean besides the indentation?

Comment: Not joking. The lack of indentation in your code blocks makes it very hard to follow the logic. In fact, look at how `checkaccount` is really used once you have a clearer understanding of the program flow.

Comment: yes for example: `Hamada 115599`

I want to change 115599 to any other password

Comment: Please indent the code properly.

Comment: checkaccount is a boolean variable, it is used to check if account exists, once the account has been checked, then it request from the user to enter new password. what is your suggested answer bro ?

Comment: `x = new Scanner(new File(...` should not be indented the same amount as `try{` on the line above. There should be some additional indentation so that the reader can immediately see where the try block ends. I do not want to read your code until you make an effort to fix similar issues in it.

Comment: ok bro, i tried some fixes on my code, i make try end before 

`if(checkaccount)` ... if this you are looking for but the same problem exists

Comment: hey guys please someone help me in my question.

Comment: I don't think you understand what I am saying, or are deliberately ignoring it. All I am asking you to do is spend a few seconds fixing the indentation of your code so it becomes legible. Indentation will not alter the semantics, but it will make the code more parseable to the human reader. Since no one appears to want to read your code, I really suggest you fix the formatting.

Answer (score 1):

If you're getting an exception here - don't just swallow it in your code. Replace the very last line with at least this:

```
catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace()
}
```

you'll get a better picture of what is going on.

Comment: thanks but please tell me what this means:


 `at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)`
 `at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:580)`
 `at java.lang.Integer.valueOf(Integer.java:766)`

Comment: In your code you have
`int foo = Integer.parseInt(user4);`
It looks like you're parsing a username not a numeric value (I guess you want to parse the password).

Comment: no, not the password, i just use this method because i want to pass the username as integer to the method `Integer.valueOf(tokens[0])==foo && checked` because it takes only integer values

Comment: public static int parseInt(String s) throws NumberFormatException

Parses the string argument as a signed decimal integer. The characters in the string must all be decimal digits, except that the first character may be an ASCII minus sign '-' ('\u002D') to indicate a negative value or an ASCII plus sign '+' ('\u002B') to indicate a positive value.
Parameters:
    s - a String containing the int representation to be parsed
Returns:
    the integer value represented by the argument in decimal.
Throws:
    NumberFormatException - if the string does not contain a parsable integer.

Comment: anyway, could you find an answer to my question :)

Comment: **NumberFormatException - if the string does not contain a parsable integer** -- you cannot pass a username (in your example: Hamada, Johny..) to the **Integer.valueOf** method!